# Ruby, random number generator and if statement

Tags: ruby, if-statement, random

After running this program, it only ever returns "miss"

What have I done wrong?

```
def method
print "Enter number from 0 to 4"
x = gets.chomp

num = rand(5)

if x == num
puts "hit"
else
puts "miss"
end
end

while 1==1
method
end
```

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gets.chomp` results in a *String*. Comparing a String to a number with equality will never be `true`, because they are completely different types.

You should convert `x` to an integer before comparison, using [`String#to_i`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-to_i):

```
x = gets.chomp.to_i
```

Also, `while 1==1` is a bit strange. This is more readable:

```
while true
  method
end
```

Or even better:

```
loop { method }
```

Comment: `String#to_i` ignores anything after the number. No need for `chomp`.

Answer (score 3):

You are reading a string from `$stdin`:

Change

```
x = gets.chomp
```

to

```
x = gets.chomp.to_i
```

Hope this helps

### Reference

[String#to_i](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-to_i)

Comment: `String#to_i` ignores anything after the number. No need for `chomp`.